# Concrete5 PNotify prompt pops up without text input and buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, concrete5, pnotify

I've copied the exact PNotify Prompt code from the site: (https://sciactive.com/pnotify/):

```
$("#show-pnotify").on('click', function() {
    var x = new PNotify({
        title: 'Password Required',
        text: 'Enter Password',
        icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-lock',
        styling: 'bootstrap3',
        hide: true,
        addclass: 'stack-modal',
        confirm: {
            prompt: true
        },
        buttons: {
            closer: false,
            sticker: false
        },
        history: {
            history: false
        }
    })
});
```

It works on their site, it works in Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/gusLfnux/2/), but it doesn't show up properly on my Concrete5 site - it shows the prompt with title and text, but no text input and no buttons are shown. Why is that? It works everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Without a whole lot else to go on, my best guess is that you're missing an import statement somewhere. Concrete5 doesn't contain *everything* from PNotify. For instance, I was using modals with Bootstrap, and I had to include the link to the full bootstrap.min.js. Download the [minified PNotify JS](https://sciactive.com/pnotify/#download), and try adding the following import statements to your header (with the proper route, of course):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="pnotify.custom.min.js"></script>
<link href="pnotify.custom.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

to your header and see if that fixes it.

Concrete5 borrows elements from a bunch of different things, but not everything from one. There's the [ConcreteAlert](https://documentation.concrete5.org/tutorials/how-to-create-alert-notifications-and-modals) that they offer, but I couldn't get it to play nice.